# How to call python function based on text box value

Tags: python, django

How to do trigger in python.

I have one text box after user enter 10 digit mobile number. i need to call one python function in that i have to call API on it. because of that how to do trigger on python.

```
<input type="text"  name="mobile"  placeholder="Please Enter 10 Digits mobile number"
 pattern="[789][0-9]{9}">
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You will have to use or create some .dataChanged event in textbox and check for this condition everytime when is the event triggered.

Comment: client side i will trigger.. How to tell to server run this function when trigger raised?

Comment: You should really do the django tutorial....

Answer (score 1):

> How to tell to server run this function when trigger raised

Post the form to a Django view that will handle it. This is HTTP you know, nothing new under the sun.

NB if you want the user to remain on the same page you will of course have to post thru an ajax call (which doesn't make much difference from the server side - a post is a post is a post...).